# Elasticsearch - How to list exact match at the top

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I am searching the word "Adana" in Elasticsearch and want it to come at top because it is the exact word, but it doesn't.

Instead "Bilmemne Adana Otel" comes at top.

Normal query doesn't do any good so I tried the boolean query with "must" and "should". But it doesn't change anything too.

In addition to that, if i write "Ada" the "Adana" should come first too.

How can we make it work right?

Query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/destinations/_search" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     “Name”: {
       "query": “Adana”
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Result:

```
{
"took" : 16,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 3.255435,
    "hits" : [
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : 3.255435,
        "_source" : {
        "name" : "Bilmemne Adana Otel"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 2.8624198,
        "_source" : {
        "name" : "Adana"
        }
    },
    {
        "_index" : "destinations",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 2.3216834,
        "_source" : {
        "name" : "Adana Airport Otel - Adana"
        }
    }
    ]
}
}
```

Index:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 2,
        "max_gram": 15
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
        ]
        }
    }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete", 
        "search_analyzer": "standard" 
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your exact matches to be on top, you could use a `keyword` field in your mapping.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can have a `bool` query that uses your `keyword` in the `should` query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Adana"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": {
              "value": "Adana"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That should push the exact match to the top.

Comment: That is working but if i search for "Ada" the order now is: "Adana Airport Otel - Adana", "Bilmemne Adana Otel" and "Adana" making it last. Can we make it so even if write "Ada" the "Adana" will again come first.